# values in excel appearing nan in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract, etl

I was working with this csv file where I have a column that I can clearly see it's content in the csv viewer:

[image: Format]

When I print rows in VSC, I get this:

[image: Format]

but when I print the dataframe I get:

[image: Format]

I went researching and I saw that this could be some sort of `ascii non readable character`. So I tried just removing it:

```
df['Partnumber'] = df['Partnumber'].replace(regex=r'[\x00-\x08\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]', value='')
```

but I still get `NaN`.

Comment: How about using this pattern: `^\\x0{2}`? so `df['partnumber'].replace(r'^\\x0{2}', '')`

Comment: Whatever wrote this CSV file has a bug where a NUL is written after the newline on data rows. You could verify by opening in binary mode and then print, say, 4096 bytes, and see what you get. Fix the thing that wrote the file if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same experience with files received from external partners. My solution was:

```
df['Partnumber'] = df['Partnumber'].apply(lambda x: x.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))
```

or

```
df['Partnumber'] = df['Partnumber'].apply(lambda x: x.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode('ascii'))
```

Since this happened often I created a function in a `utils.py` file

```
def csv_cleaner(text):
    return text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
```

that I imported

```
import pandas as pd
from utils import csv_cleaner

df = pd.read_csv('path_to_your_file.csv', converters={'Partnumber': csv_cleaner})
```